# How to check v-radio on the edit screen?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am practicing the code example below.

I applied Vuetify.

This is the edit screen showing the data fetched from the API.
The problem is that the selected `v-radio` is not checked.

What is the problem?

```js
<v-radio-group v-model="designType" :mandatory="false" row>
  <v-radio
    v-for="n in 3"
    :key="n"
    :label="`Type ${n}`"
    :value="n"
    :checked="n === designType"
    :aria-checked="n === designType"
  />
  {{designType}}  //<<----- test value is no problem
</v-radio-group>
...
// script
data() => ({
  ...
  designType: 1,
  ...
}),
mounted() {
  this.edit = true
  this.formEdit()
,
methods: {
async formEdit() {
  const apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:3100/cards/'
  await this.$axios.get(apiUrl + this.$route.params.id).then(res => {
    this.designType = res.data.designType
   })
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `{{ n === designType }}` and see if it's true or false

Comment: Tnx Daniel!  but I have parse Error.

Comment: Oh, it's because `n` isn't available outside `v-radio`. Um, is there the option to have a closing tag? If not just wrap it in a div, put the `v-for` on that div and then try `{{ n === designType }}`

Comment: The problem was not solved, so I had to change it to a pure <input type = "radio"> tag.
Tnx Daniel